# IMPORTRANGE Error Loading Data Limit of 600 shares reached

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api

We have a master Google sheet that is updated a number of times a day with the list of our Contacts and other data from our CRM

I have a number of different spreadsheets that use IMPORTRANGE to grab data from that spreadsheet. In the last few days we seem to have hit a limit that i didn't know about:

I can only "share" the access to a spreadsheet 600 times:

https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/7338880?sjid=1125066602944498140-EU&visit_id=21693241867192-3852471190774448699&rd=1

I was chatting with Google help but they suggested coming here and were unable to answer my questions:

1. Am I able to "rescind" some of the 600 accesses i granted? If yes how. If No:
2. Can I go below the 600 count by a) deleting a file where the request came from, or b) Going into that file and deleting the cells with IMPORTRANGE in them?
3. Does the IMPORTRANGE count for all files i created from the beginning of time or only "open" files. in other words if I created my first IMPORTRANGE call in a file in 2020 that i no longer open is that still being counted against the 600?
4. If answers 1 through3 are "You are screwed" as you cannot get below the 600 count once the Genie is out of the lamp then going forward what is best practice?
   a) Create CRMSYNCHFILE#1, then use an IMPORTRANGE to copy the Data to CRMSYCHFILE#2, #3,#4 etc and then having my destination files rotate to the next file when the previous one fills up? If so Must I open CRMSYCHFILE#2 at least once a day for it to grab the data from CRMSYCHFILE#1 or does IMPRTRANGE work even if the files are not opened?

Any other suggestions?

I have not yet tried deleting one of the destinations files

Comment: Is this issue programming related?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It is programming related only inasmuch as I use IMPORTRANGE in one google sheet to get data from another